# Create a filter from a user selected data validation list

Tags: google-apps-script, filter

I am trying to use Google apps script to create a filter across row 1 on 'Data' sheet tab. The filter is taken from a data validation list on 'Dashboard' sheet - cell 'I7', this is where the user changes the filter options.

e.g. if user selects 'Shopfloor' on drop down menu on Dashboard sheet. then this will change the filter on Data sheet for column E to show only Shopfloor staff.

I am almost there but am getting an error with setColumnFilterCriteria. Any help is much appreciated.

```
/* SET FOLLOWING VARIABLES */
var dropSS           = "Dashboard";     //Name of the sheet which dropdown list to be created
var primaryDropRange = "I7";            //Range which primary dropdown set

//CREATE PRIMARY DROPDOWN LIST
function onOpen(e) {
  /* SET FOLLOWING VARIABLES */
  var dataSS           = "Lists";         //Name of the sheet that contain data for dropdown lists
  var primaryDataRange = "E1:E5";         //Data range for primary dropdown
  var primaryDropList  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(dataSS).getRange(primaryDataRange).getValues();
  var primaryDropRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(dropSS).getRange(primaryDropRange);
  var BA = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(primaryDropList).build();
  primaryDropRange.setDataValidation(BA);
}

function filterBA(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var selBA = ss.getSheetByName(dropSS).getRange('I7').getValue();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Data');
  var filter = sheet.getFilter();
  //var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().setVisibleValues(selBA).build();
  if(sheet.getFilter() != null) {                                                                   // Check if filter already exists and remove filter if true
     sheet.getFilter().remove();
  }
  var FilterRange = sheet.getDataRange().createFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(4, selBA);
}
```

Link to my sample spreadsheet - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/191S0DNlxczKKi2SJuc45CXxDXZxXH4xNpjgEJxf46X8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `filterBA` function should look like this:

```
function filterBA(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var selBA = ss.getSheetByName(dropSS).getRange('I7').getValue();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Data');

  // Check if filter already exists and remove filter if true
  if(sheet.getFilter() != null) {  
     sheet.getFilter().remove();
  }

  // Create criteria
  var newCriteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenTextEqualTo(selBA).build();
  // The 1-indexed position of the column
  sheet.getDataRange().createFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(5, newCriteria);      
}
```

#### Your issues:

- `criteria` parameter accepts type `FilterCriteria` variable, not the exact value you want to filter with.
- `column` parameter is 1-indexed, not 0. All methods for sheets that accepts columns are 1-indexed.

#### Output:

[image: output1]

[image: output2]

#### Reference:

- [setColumnFilterCriteria](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter#setColumnFilterCriteria(Integer,FilterCriteria))

Answer (score -1):

This can be done without any script using Data Validation and the QUERY() function. Take a look at the Dropdown tab on this sample sheet, A2 has the Data Validation based on a table. B2 has the QUERY() function based on the value in A1.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qbLOjTdzISICTKyUp_jK6gZbQCt-OwtDYYy3HNJygeE/edit#gid=795322028

[image]

[image]

Here is the formula in B2

```
=query(Invoices!A1:B, "select A where B='"&A2&"' LABEL A ''", TRUE)
```

In this sheet the first three tabs are relevant for this answer, you can ignore the others

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution, however this isn't suitable for my task as I need to add to add to my 'Data' tab on a weekly basis and will create more work for me in the long run. This will be a great alternative in another scenerio such as invoicing like your example. Thanks for sharing, as I'm sure it will help others in the future.